# Issue with MYSQL lc_time_names

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to the retrieve the time as '3:30 م' instead of '3:30 PM' from Mysql (like CultureInfo in .NET)

By setting the lc_time_names = 'ar_EG' it still the same.

Here what i did

```
SET lc_time_names = 'ar_EG';
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(NOW(),'%h:%i %p') AS 'Time';
```

[image: img]
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html

I don't know why 0 rows is affected ? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [MySQL Server Locale Support](http://MySQL%20Server%20Locale%20Support) link you've shared we can read:

> The locale indicated by the `lc_time_names` system variable controls the language used to display **day and month** names and abbreviations. This variable affects the **output from** the **`DATE_FORMAT()`**, `DAYNAME()`, and `MONTHNAME()` functions.

It says nothing about `TIME_FORMAT()` or AM/PM. Since it does not seem to work, I presume it's just not supported:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'ar_EG';
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%l %p, %r, %a, %b');
```

```
4 PM, 04:28:06 PM, خ, مار
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply pass the third parameter as a local value. ^^

> SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2023-06-15", '%W %d %M %Y','it_IT') as date;

output: giovedì 15 giugno 2023

> SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2023-06-15", '%W %d %M %Y','fr_FR') as date;

output  : jeudi 15 juin 2023

> SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2023-06-15", '%W %d %M %Y','ja_JP') as date;

output : 木曜日 15 6月 2023

for more information, here  [MySQL Server Locale Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locale-support.html)

Answer (score 0):

Zero rows effected means zero database rows effected.  You have not changed the data.  The set commands is setting a variable but not changing table data.

Comment: When I set the command, I think mysql settings is changed, so when I execute the Now() it should give the time according to the new setting which is ar_eg format. There is no rows in my database I had to update inorder to see the results.

Comment: what do you suggest ?

Comment: @AhmedSamy Not sure you understood David. The `0 row(s) affected` only means that `SET lc_time_names = 'ar_EG';` does not alter any database table.